# Database schema restructuring to optimize performance and space

Tags: database-design, sql-server-2012, database-schema, database-performance

I am working on **SQL SERVER 2012 Express Edition**, (I am not database architect but c# dev only) I had table which had 30 columns and 10+ million rows

```
CID      PID    DID     FID  DateTimeStamp   P01    P02   P03.....P30

CI1001  PI1001  DI1001  30  2017-04-02 9:14  12     230   230

CI1001  PI1001  DI1002  51  2017-04-02 9:14  34     3430  3430

CI1001  PI1001  DI1003  5   2017-04-02 9:14  56     340   340

CI1001  PI1001  DI1004  4   2017-04-02 9:14  78     340   340

CI1001  PI1001  DI1005  5   2017-04-02 9:14  33     340   340
```

The issue I am facing with the present schema is

1. I am not able to achieve dynamic column adding in this structure. 
   E.g. Sometime at few of my customer’s place I need to add additional columns beside “P01, P02 ... P30” such as P31, P32.
2. It’s not necessary that all the column i.e. P01, P02... P30 have values all the time, it may possible there will be value for P01, P02... P020 and rest will go empty/null. So the allocated space goes waste there.
3. In the current schema I need to apply the 2, 3 indexes to maintain the performance of my queries and procedure. It works fine but unfortunately indexes itself consumed the 30% of storage and since its express edition it create file size restriction problem for me in few months.

Now I am thinking to split the above table schema in two tables such as

The table will hold unique code for each column such as (P01, P02, P03)

```
   CID       PID        PCODE      PNAME
   CI1001   PI1001      C1          P01
   CI1001   PI1001      C2          P02
   CI1001   PI1001      C3          P03
   CI1001   PI1001      C4          P04
   CI1001   PI1001      C5          P05
```

This will be actual transaction table where for each column I will insert one new row.

```
CID     PID     DID     FID   PCODE       DateTimeStamp            Value
CI1001  PI1001  DI1001   30   C1          2017-04-02 9:14          230
CI1001  PI1001  DI1002   51   C2          2017-04-02 9:14          3430
CI1001  PI1001  DI1003   3    C3          2017-04-02 9:14          340
CI1001  PI1001  DI1004   4    C3          2017-04-02 9:14          340
CI1001  PI1001  DI1005   5    C5          2017-04-02 9:14          340
```

With this schema I am sure that this will enable to add any no. Of columns at runtime but I am not sure if I will get any performance & size gains with this. 
Can anyone please suggest whether this approach is correct or any inputs on how to design such a schema?

**Edited**

With this schema 3 of my issues which I explained above are getting fixed and I made some trial run on this and with just a index all my query set run smoothly so performance is not the issue but the space as it consumed literally 7 times more than the previous One.

Below is schema of two tables

**MAIN TRANSACTION TABLE:-**

```
    ClientID      varchar(8)    
    PlantID       varchar(8)
    DeviceID      varchar(8)    
    FeederID      tinyint   
    PCODE         varchar(10)   
    Dates         date
    TimeStamp     time(7)   
    VALUE         decimal(19, 3)
```

**TABALE WITH UNIQUE CODE FOR EACH COL**

```
ClientID     varchar(8) 
PlantID      varchar(8) 
PCODE        varchar(10)    
PARANAME     varchar(15)
```

So I am thinking to change table schema, Can anyone please suggest any inputs on how to design such a schema?

Comment: I think this approach will work in your situation. Make sure each columns get appropriate data-type to reduce the storage size and if possible then avoid any large column as a key column in an index.

Comment: Please use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & ERDs. Textual content in images/links cannot be searched for & cannot be cut & pasted.

Comment: Why do you introduce the PCODE-PNAME/PARANAME indirection? Just for the space difference between varchar(10) and varchar(15)?